# Does "I like sports especially playing badminton." sound natural?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

> 1. I like sports especially playing badminton.
> 2. I like sports especially like playing badminton.
> 3. I'm fond of sports and especially like playing badminton.

Which one is correct and sounds more natural? I know the third one should be correct but I am wondering if first and second are ok?

Answer (score 3):

As you said that you know in your comment, the 3rd sentence is correct. 1 and 2 are not.

2 is no good because you repeat the word “like” without repeating the subject, and the punctuation doesn’t work. The following would be grammatical:

> I like sports; I especially like playing badminton.

The semicolon separates the two related but different points. This could also work as two different sentences.

1 doesn’t work too well, also because of missing punctuation. And the word “playing” seems out of place- the way it’s currently worded, it sounds like “playing badminton” is a sport you especially like, which doesn’t make sense. You could either say badminton is a sport you like, or badminton is a sport you like playing. So either of these:

> I like sports, especially badminton.

Or

> I like playing sports, especially badminton.

Comment: Exactly. The **sentences** in the question sounded weird the moment I read them. I don't know if they are grammatically correct! But they do not suit my ears. `I like playing sports, especially badminton.` is the one which I was genuinely looking for. :D

Comment: The ';' in "I like sports; I especially like playing badminton." is a little hard for me. How about "I like sports and I especially like playing badminton." ? I know it consists of two simple sentences and should be fine. (I will search more about ';' ;later)

Comment: @Austin yes, the ‘and’ works in a similar way to a semicolon. Your new sentence here, “I like sports and I especially like playing badminton” is grammatical. What is hard or confusing to you about using a semicolon? (Post a new question about semicolons if you like.)